# Export Credit Card Data from Volusion

Tags: asp.net

We have a client using Volusion as a storefront/e-commerce solution. We need to export purchase data, including credit card information, from it into a fulfillment provider who will then run a customer's credit card only when/if the item they ordered ships.

We have access to the server running IIS, we have the API on the fulfillment provider side to send this data over HTTPS, and we can build a simple polling ASP.Net app that runs on the same PCI-certified server that holds the CC data that moves data from Volusion to the fulfillment provider securely.

What remains is how to get the data out of Volusion. We've had several answers and none have panned out:

- Use the API. The API documentation is very light, and doesn't make clear how to get CC data out.
- Fill out a verification form and you can "view" it. This came from their customer service department, but they were very shaky on details.
- Query the database directly. It's not clear whether this is feasible.

If someone here has handled external credit card processing on Volusion before, we're interested in how to get this done. What the process is to get these fields enabled in the XML API and the format of those fields would be enough, or some other approach - whatever gets us to the finish line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Volusion will not ever release customer's Credit Card information to you via an API or any other means.

maybe this will help you do more research:

http://devwiki.volusion.com/index.php/Customers_Export
http://devwiki.volusion.com/index.php/Orders_Export - the closest you can get is the last 4 of the CC number.

A better design pattern would be to charge the customer at purchase time, if the drop shipper cannot fulfill the order cancel the order and refund the transaction.

Comment: +1.  I doubt ANY PCI-Compliant payment processor would ever do this.  This is one of those things that is SUCH a bad idea it's not worth even considering.  @Chris Mischini - you'd be better off re-examining the business practice because this is just not going to happen.

Comment: Another consultant says he's done this several times with Volusion, but refuses to say how. The problem is he only knows PHP, which Volusion's environment doesn't support. He'd be pulling the data out of Volusion, into yet another set of servers to get it into PHP, then finally out to the fulfillment provider - seems like unnecessary risk to the client. We'd really like to hear from someone who's done this before with Volusion.

Comment: @DavidStratton PCI does not forbid this kind of movement of data. It rather requires that you document and justify it with a business purpose - and secure it. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf

Comment: @Chris I think if you need that workflow and want to have this kinda of control you are going to need to write your own cart. I'd use Authorize.net's AIM + CIM Products. CIM stores the CC info remotely in a PCI compliant manner, and aim to actually process the order. steps: save customer and requested order, send order to drop shipper, when drop shipper notifies you that order was fulfilled, call up CIM info for that order and charge the order total against it. Double check Terms of Use on CIM before investing heavily on that route though.

Comment: @FrancisVonAwesomesauce We tried the AIM/CIM route, where we authorize out to Auth.Net, leave the details there, and pass a transaction ID to the fulfillment provider. The fulfillment provider doesn't support it. In addition, taking the details from a place they're already stored (Volusion) and sending them securely to the provider is not substantially less secure, in terms of both storage and transit. We really do need to export this from Volusion and into the fulfillment provider. Any way that's done will do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extract the credit card number through the Volusion API.  The only way to do it is contact Volusion Support have them enable the displaying of credit card numbers within your Admin.  They will probably have you sign a wavier that you will follow PCI compliance.

Comment: There is technically a workaround in this approach of having the exporting system impersonate a user logging into the admin interface and screen scraping, but it's a long, long walk. The right answer is in one of the comments above - talk the client out of Volusion.

Comment: As of 2/22/2012, they have prohibited this.  Yes, it was once possible.